# If $|f(x)|\leq\frac{C}{(1+|x|^2)^N}$, prove its Fourier transform$\hat{f}$ is well-defined, smooth and in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Given a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with the property that for all natural number $N$, there exists a constant $C$ (depending on $N$) such that the inequality $|f(x)|\leq\frac{C}{(1+|x|^2)^N}$ holds for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how can I show that $f$ has a Fourier transform that (a) is well-defined, (b) is smooth, and (c) belongs to $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? I know that a function has a well-defined Fourier transform if it is integrable. The Fourier transform would belong to $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if also the original function belongs to this space. Having the inequality stated above, is there a way of proving that $f$ belongs to both spaces $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? And how can one show that in this case, its Fourier transform is even smooth? The result would follow if $f$ were a Schwartz function. I have not learned about Sobolev spaces yet, so I need a method that does not use them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer uses some non-elementary theory and therefore it is a comment. Fourier transform of your function belongs to the intersection of all Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Therefore by Sobolev embedding theorems your function is smooth and belongs to $L_2$.

Comment: Is there a difference to your previous question [Prove: If $|f(x)|\leq\frac{C}{(1+|x|^2)^N}$, then its Fourier transform$\hat{f}$ is well-defined, smooth and in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494017/42969) ?

Comment: No Martin R, but nobody answered my previous question.

Comment: You only asked your old question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494017/prove-if-fx-leq-fracc1x2n-then-its-fourier-transform-hatf) 8 hours ago. Have a little patience instead of posting the same question multiple times. Also, you should really try to show that $\int 1/(1+|x|)^{N}dx < \infty$ for $N$ large enough (depending on n). This will answer all your questions except the smoothness. For the smoothness see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement